# patch a go function inside of a binary

Tags: go, reverse-engineering, patch

I want to modify my go binary so that the function time.Sleep does wait for one second only.

By inspecting closely said binary, i managed to find its address and disassembled the function using gdb. But i'm stuck on where is the first argument actually used...
How could i patch the function so that the first argument is not used, instead it has a low static value so that i don't have to wait for too long.

---

Here is the disassembly:

```
   0x0000000000460900 <+0>: cmp    rsp,QWORD PTR [r14+0x10]
   0x0000000000460904 <+4>: jbe    0x460a49 <time.Sleep+329>
   0x000000000046090a <+10>:    sub    rsp,0x38
   0x000000000046090e <+14>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x30],rbp
   0x0000000000460913 <+19>:    lea    rbp,[rsp+0x30]
   0x0000000000460918 <+24>:    nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
   0x0000000000460920 <+32>:    test   rax,rax
   0x0000000000460923 <+35>:    jle    0x460a3f <time.Sleep+319>
   0x0000000000460929 <+41>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x40],rax
   0x000000000046092e <+46>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x28],r14
   0x0000000000460933 <+51>:    mov    rcx,QWORD PTR [r14+0x170]
   0x000000000046093a <+58>:    test   rcx,rcx
   0x000000000046093d <+61>:    jne    0x460981 <time.Sleep+129>
   0x000000000046093f <+63>:    lea    rax,[rip+0x8b85a]        # 0x4ec1a0
   0x0000000000460946 <+70>:    call   0x40dc80 <runtime.newobject>
   0x000000000046094b <+75>:    mov    rdi,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x28]
   0x0000000000460950 <+80>:    test   BYTE PTR [rdi],al
   0x0000000000460952 <+82>:    cmp    DWORD PTR [rip+0x187b27],0x0        # 0x5e8480 <runtime.writeBarrier>
   0x0000000000460959 <+89>:    jne    0x460964 <time.Sleep+100>
   0x000000000046095b <+91>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rdi+0x170],rax
   0x0000000000460962 <+98>:    jmp    0x460979 <time.Sleep+121>
   0x0000000000460964 <+100>:   lea    rcx,[rdi+0x170]
   0x000000000046096b <+107>:   mov    rdx,rdi
   0x000000000046096e <+110>:   mov    rdi,rcx
   0x0000000000460971 <+113>:   call   0x463c00 <runtime.gcWriteBarrier>
   0x0000000000460976 <+118>:   mov    rdi,rdx
   0x0000000000460979 <+121>:   mov    rcx,rax
   0x000000000046097c <+124>:   mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x40]
   0x0000000000460981 <+129>:   test   BYTE PTR [rcx],al
   0x0000000000460983 <+131>:   cmp    DWORD PTR [rip+0x187af6],0x0        # 0x5e8480 <runtime.writeBarrier>
   0x000000000046098a <+138>:   jne    0x460999 <time.Sleep+153>
   0x000000000046098c <+140>:   lea    rdx,[rip+0x9d36d]        # 0x4fdd00
   0x0000000000460993 <+147>:   mov    QWORD PTR [rcx+0x18],rdx
   0x0000000000460997 <+151>:   jmp    0x4609a9 <time.Sleep+169>
   0x0000000000460999 <+153>:   lea    rdi,[rcx+0x18]
   0x000000000046099d <+157>:   lea    rdx,[rip+0x9d35c]        # 0x4fdd00
   0x00000000004609a4 <+164>:   call   0x463d20 <runtime.gcWriteBarrierDX>
   0x00000000004609a9 <+169>:   mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x20],rcx
   0x00000000004609ae <+174>:   lea    rdx,[rip+0x7298b]        # 0x4d3340
   0x00000000004609b5 <+181>:   mov    QWORD PTR [rcx+0x20],rdx
   0x00000000004609b9 <+185>:   cmp    DWORD PTR [rip+0x187ac0],0x0        # 0x5e8480 <runtime.writeBarrier>
   0x00000000004609c0 <+192>:   jne    0x4609cd <time.Sleep+205>
   0x00000000004609c2 <+194>:   mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x28]
   0x00000000004609c7 <+199>:   mov    QWORD PTR [rcx+0x28],rdx
   0x00000000004609cb <+203>:   jmp    0x4609db <time.Sleep+219>
   0x00000000004609cd <+205>:   lea    rdi,[rcx+0x28]
   0x00000000004609d1 <+209>:   mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x28]
   0x00000000004609d6 <+214>:   call   0x463d20 <runtime.gcWriteBarrierDX>
   0x00000000004609db <+219>:   nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
   0x00000000004609e0 <+224>:   call   0x465600 <runtime.nanotime1>
   0x00000000004609e5 <+229>:   xorps  xmm15,xmm15
   0x00000000004609e9 <+233>:   mov    r14,QWORD PTR fs:0xfffffffffffffff8
   0x00000000004609f2 <+242>:   mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rsp]
   0x00000000004609f6 <+246>:   mov    rcx,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x40]
   0x00000000004609fb <+251>:   add    rax,rcx
   0x00000000004609fe <+254>:   mov    rbx,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x20]
   0x0000000000460a03 <+259>:   mov    QWORD PTR [rbx+0x38],rax
   0x0000000000460a07 <+263>:   test   rax,rax
   0x0000000000460a0a <+266>:   jge    0x460a1a <time.Sleep+282>
   0x0000000000460a0c <+268>:   movabs rdx,0x7fffffffffffffff
   0x0000000000460a16 <+278>:   mov    QWORD PTR [rbx+0x38],rdx
   0x0000000000460a1a <+282>:   lea    rax,[rip+0x9d417]        # 0x4fde38
   0x0000000000460a21 <+289>:   mov    ecx,0x13
   0x0000000000460a26 <+294>:   mov    edi,0x13
   0x0000000000460a2b <+299>:   mov    esi,0x1
   0x0000000000460a30 <+304>:   call   0x436d80 <runtime.gopark>
   0x0000000000460a35 <+309>:   mov    rbp,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x30]
   0x0000000000460a3a <+314>:   add    rsp,0x38
   0x0000000000460a3e <+318>:   ret
   0x0000000000460a3f <+319>:   mov    rbp,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x30]
   0x0000000000460a44 <+324>:   add    rsp,0x38
   0x0000000000460a48 <+328>:   ret
   0x0000000000460a49 <+329>:   mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x8],rax
   0x0000000000460a4e <+334>:   call   0x461b00 <runtime.morestack_noctxt>
   0x0000000000460a53 <+339>:   mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x8]
   0x0000000000460a58 <+344>:   jmp    0x460900 <time.Sleep>
End of assembler dump.
```

I am trying to change the time.go file on my computer.
While i find this library to have the timeSleep --> time.Sleep linked function:

/usr/share/go-1.18/src/runtime/time.go

gdb is telling me that this [/usr/local/go/src/runtime/time.go] is where he puts breakpoints when i put a breakpoint on time.Sleep.
So i'm confused if 1) changing this file will affect my already precompiled binary 2) this is the correct file that is called when the binary launches ?

Edit:

I can change the source code using hexedit, the issue is how can i know where to find the right byte to change to make it work ?

Comment: 1. no. changing the source code won't affect the compiled binary; 2. when the binary launches, it won't "call" the source file.

Comment: While I commend you for the effort you've put in for this, it would probably be a lot simpler to fork the source code on github, modify it, and then build your own binary. For reference, this is probably what you will need to modify [sleep.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/time.go#L178)